# How to remove duplicate numbers that occurred more than twice, but keep the first two occurances

Tags: java

So I came across this problem in Java that wants to remove a list of number that has occurred more than twice but keeping the order, and the first two occurrences.

For example, if the list is 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 10

the expected output would be 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 10

I've tried several methods, including using a counter int to keep track of the occurrences and filter it out, but I am not sure how I can go about it

```
class DeDup {
    // function to find the element occurring more than 3 times
    static void get2Occurrences(int arr[]) {
        int i;
        int count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                    count++;
            }
            if (count < 3 && count > 0) {
                //return arr[i];
                System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
            } else {
                for (int k = 2; k > 0; k--) {
                    System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // driver code
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int arr[] = new int[]{ 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 10 }; 
        //expected output: 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 10
        //int n = arr.length;
        get2Occurrences(arr);
    }
}
```

the expected output would be 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 10

but i got 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 10, 10,

Comment: Is the task for numbers from 1 to N or for any numbers?

Comment: So you would like to remove only elements that occur more than 2 times in your list? @MCO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution, you can change the number of repetitions from three to another.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 10};
Map<Integer, Integer> counting = new HashMap<>();
for (Integer current : arr) {
    int count = counting.compute(current, (x, n) -> n == null ? 1 : n + 1);
    if (count < 3) {
        System.out.print(current + ", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this line:
```
int count = counting.compute(current, (x, n) -> n == null ? 1 : n + 1)
```

Comment: When a map does not contain a value(n) by key(x), one are added to it, when the map contains a key, the existing value(n) increases.

Comment: This is a very smart approach, thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 4):

I would do it using a pair of `Set`s: `Set.add` returns a boolean indicating whether the element was added. Hence:

```
boolean b = set1.add(num) || set2.add(num);
```

will be `true` if it was added into either set - and it will only try to add it to `set2` if it was already in `set1` - and `false` otherwise, meaning it was present in both sets already.

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>();

for (Integer a : arr) {
  if (set1.add(a) || set2.add(a)) {
    System.out.print(a + ", ");
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/XU6ZhW)

Comment: Can you explain how this wouldnt eliminate the "keep the first 2 occurances" rule?

Comment: @MCO I don't know what you're asking. I've added a link to a demo in Ideone, showing the output you require.

Comment: think I just dont understand how the hashsets can make it work

Comment: Upon research I think i understand more now, correct me if im wrong, but since hashset doesnt allow duplicates, you created to hashsets and ||(or) it so it has exactly 2 occurances

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the number of occurrences found for each element.

Something like this:

```
  static void get2Occurrences(int arr[])
  {
    // Initialize occurrences found
    Hashtable<Integer, Integer> found_elms = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

    // Loop over all elements
    int     counter;
    int     number;
    Integer found;
    for (counter = 0; counter < arr.length; counter++)
    {
      number = arr[counter];
      found = found_elms.get(number);
      if (found == null)
        found = 1;
      else
        found = found + 1;
      found_elms.put(number, found);
      if (found < 3)
        System.out.print(number + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();

  } // get2Occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose an insert filter : go through each element with a for loop and insert it into a response array if the response arrays doesnt contain it 2 times yet

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

...

```
List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
 for (int i : arr) {
    if (lst.lastIndexOf(i) == lst.indexOf(i)) {
            lst.add(i);
    }
  }
  return lst.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with in the end

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class DeDup { 

    // function to find the element occurring more than 3 times 
    static void get2Occurrences(ArrayList<Integer> arr) 
    { 
        for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){    
            int count=0;
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++){ 
               if(arr.get(j)==arr.get(i)){
               count++;
               }
        }
        if (count>=2){
            arr.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Output: "+arr);;
    }

    // driver code  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList( 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 10));
        //expected output: 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 10
        //int n = arr.length; 
        System.out.println("Input: "+arr);
        get2Occurrences(arr); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Iteartor:

```
List<Integer> array = Lists.newArrayList(2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 10);
Map<Integer, Integer> control = new HashMap<>();

Iterator<Integer> iterator = array.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   Integer element = iterator.next();
   Integer occurrences = control.getOrDefault(element, 0);

   if (occurrences >= 2) {
       iterator.remove();
   } else {
       control.put(element, occurrences + 1);
   }
}
```